# Java-Spring Json field with associated classes

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-data

I want to make a json field in my spring entity like this

```java
@Type(type = "json")
@Column(name = "LIFE_CYCLE_RULES")
private List<S3LifeCycleRule> lifeCycleRules;
```

but the class S3LifeCycleRule has associated classes

```java
private S3LifeCycleExpiration expiration;
private String id;
private String prefix;
private S3LifeCycleFilter filter;
private Boolean status;
private List<S3LifeCycleTransition> transitions;
```

S3LifeCycleExpiration.java:

```java
@JsonSerialize
public record S3LifeCycleExpiration(
        Instant Date,
        int Days,
        Boolean ExpiredObjectDeleteMarker
) {
}
```

S3LifeCycleTransition.java:

```java
@JsonSerialize
public record S3LifeCycleTransition(
        Instant date,
        int days,
        S3ObjectStorageClass storageClass
) {
}
```

(S3ObjectStorageClass is an enumerator)

S3LifeCycleFilter.java:

```java
@JsonSerialize
public record S3LifeCycleFilter (
        String prefix,
        S3LifeCycleTag tag,
        S3LifeCycleAnd and
){
}
```

S3LifeCycleTag.java:

```java
@JsonSerialize
public record S3LifeCycleTag(
        String key,
        String value
) {}
```

S3LifeCycleAnd.java:

```java
@JsonSerialize
public record S3LifeCycleAnd(
        String prefix,
        List<S3LifeCycleTag> tags
) {
}
```

Before I added the JsonSerialize annotation the application did not work entirely, but after I added it the fields: expiration, filter and transitions stayed empty:

the output Json:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "Life_Cycle_Rule_For_5_Days",
        "filter": {},
        "prefix": null,
        "status": true,
        "expiration": {},
        "transitions": []
    }
]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem was with the records, it worked after I transformed them to normal classes and added default constructors.

I changed the files S3LifeCycleAnd, S3LifeCycleExpiration, S3LifeCycleFileter, S3LifeCycleRule and S3LifeCycleTag to normal classes and added their constructors, getters and setters normally

S3LifeCycleAnd.java:

```java
@JsonSerialize
public class S3LifeCycleAnd {
    private String prefix;
    private List<S3LifeCycleTag> tags;

    public S3LifeCycleAnd(){}
    public S3LifeCycleAnd(String prefix, List<S3LifeCycleTag> tags){
        this.tags = tags;
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public String getPrefix() {
        return prefix;
    }

    public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public List<S3LifeCycleTag> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<S3LifeCycleTag> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

the same for the others.

Thanks.

Comment: I mentioned the changes, but it seems like I have to wait for 2 days to mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding getters to your classes, it would be easy with [`Lombok`](https://projectlombok.org/) `@Getter` annotation.

If it don't work, then you need to create custom serializers for all classes and change their annotations to 
`@JsonSerialize(using = SomeCustomSerializer.class)`
[Serializer demo](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations) (check paragraph 2.7).
[Jackson – Custom Serializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)